# Django admin user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am reading 2 quite popular django books, both recommend using django's admin user model, template to create user for the site I am building. It feels odd. Isn't it dangerous to add our site's users with the admin users that uses Django admin interface?

If that recommendation is right, how can I add more attributes to that admin user model (hence add more columns to the auth_user table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they recommend is to use the [`Users` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/) provided by the `django.contrib.auth` application.  It's the standard in django and many other apps depend on this model to integrate with user data. Being the django admin one of them.

Note that not all users created using this model have access to the admin site. Only the ones with is_staff set to True.

To assign extra user information on the Users model you should use [Profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).